# Oracle database timestamp(6) when converting to snowflake timestamp_ntz throws error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, datetime-format

**I have a data in the source system, which looks like, the following below**

> "02-FEB-10 05.25.21.367709000 AM"

**But when i try to convert the data into snowflake by using timestamp_ntz it throws**

> "failed to cast variant error."

As per the Documentation and compatability it suggests timestamp can do the work but it doesn't.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-datetime.html

Let me know an approach in solving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a format parsing issue. Here's a parse string that works:

```
select try_to_timestamp_ntz('02-FEB-10 05.25.21.367709000 AM', 'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.FF AM');
```

Comment: In my case the destination data type is, timestamp_ntz, may i know why it isn't converting, without explicitly passing through the function !